# Duplicate import entries in PE file

Tags: windows, executable, portable-executable

I am doing some bulk analytics on PE files, while parsing the import table of a PE file, I'm finding that many PE files import duplicate entries for a given DLL... why is this?  what does this functionally provide?

For instance, a dump of example.exe import table shows:

Kernel32.dll
User32.dll
blah.dll
Kernel32.dll
Kernel32.dll
User32.dll
shell32.dll

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the whole information of the Import Address Table of your binary to better figure out?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the PE that you're analysing has been patched to import additional functions, since most of binaries have their Import Address Table quite packed so adding an entry into an existing module is fairly impossible.